# Is it possible in android to play an audio file over a phone call and receiver should hear it?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, call

I search about it a lot but got nothing. I just want to know is it possible or not? If yes than how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.
The simple fact is the microphone / input audio stream during a phone call is not able to be pre-processed or replaced with another stream of any form.
So simply while one would think its easy to use media during a call, it simply is not possible due to the way the android system processes the audio.